# JS API Яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

На сайте прикрутил, используя

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

карту Яндекса с определенным позиционированием, задаваемым функцией `initMap()`.
Также есть код, выводящий на страницу `div` объект, к которому привязывается плеер:

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
  sources: [{
   file: "rtmp://***.***.***.***:port/live/blabla.stream"
}],
   height: 360,
   width: 640
});
```

Можно ли вывести на карту марку, при раскрытии которой появлялся бы тот самый **плеер**? Все попытки привели по итогу к тому, что обрабатывалось событие открытия баллуна (содержимое метки), при котором отрабатывал `JS` код плеера.

И при раскрытии метки и появлении баллуна, плеер появлялся,но в стороне карты, а не внутри марки. Как реализовать желаемый вариант?

Comment: Пробовали добавить плеер внутрь балуна метки через свой макет? [Вот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout?from=SO)

Comment: Да, я видел этот пример, пытался по нему делать, заработало только со второго раза. В итоге все работает нужным образом в плане появления плеера. Возникли проблемы с изменением параметров самой метки. Формируется метка с балуном, для которого создавался свой макет: var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
        [46.374180, 48.054385],
        {name: 'Player'},
        {iconLayout:'default#image',iconImageHref: 'images/cam.png', iconImageSize: [30, 42],iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]},
        {balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayout}); В таком случае, метка меняется, но балун не открывается.

Comment: А в таком? var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark( [46.374180, 48.054385], {name: 'Player'}, {iconLayout:'default#image',iconImageHref: 'images/cam.png', iconImageSize: [30, 42],iconImageOffset: [-5, -38], balloonContentLayout: BalloonContentLayout});

Comment: Метка принимает три параметра, а вы передаёте ей четыре. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/

Comment: Да, все верно, в таком варианте все работает корректно, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Есть соответствующий пример в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/panorama_in_balloon?from=SO